# TeXnicCenter reports error despite correct execution

Tags: errors, texniccenter

I've not had any particular issues with TeXnicCenter until recently.  This past week it has been reporting an error in all compiled documents.  The error is from the first line of the output, which makes no sense, and doesn't impede output, meaning I get my PDF without issue.  There is also no mention of any error in the .log file.

[image: Error on first line of output, no error message, no mention of it in log]

Of course, there might be fire somewhere, given the smoke, and it really annoys me to see "1 error(s)" at the bottom when there's nothing wrong.  It also means I can't turn on "stop execution if there is an error".

Some possible causes:

- I recently installed BitDefender.
- I recently uninstalled NuancePDF reader (it had come on the computer, and worked "fine" until shortly after the new year, when it started crashing after loading any document.  I simply replaced it with Foxit).

I don't know if installing BitDefender is what broke Nuance or not.  I have changed my build profile to use Foxit (once I realized that setting was in the build profile).  As far as I know, there was only one place to change that, and I only needed to change the program itself, not the commandline args.

If anyone can shed some light on why this is occurring I'd greatly appreciate it.  It doesn't prevent me working, but it frustrates me and concerns me, as there may be an underlying issue somewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how to help here and the problem itself seems to me more off-topic. What you can do in my eyes: Check _every_ output profile in the Viewer tab for remnants of your old PDF viewer, and deactivate BitDefender and make a run.

Comment: I tried with BitDefender deactivated and that didn't help.  There is also no mention of the previous PDF reader in any log file produced.
I also tested with just running pdflatex by command line (cmd prompt) and the program works fine and returns an "error" code of 0, so no hints there.